# String-to-string correction algorithm

Tags: string, matching

I'm not sure I've titled this post correctly, but I'm wondering if there's a name for this type of algorithm:

What I'm trying to accomplish is to create a **minimal set of instructions** to go from one string to its **permutation**, so for example:

```
    STACKOVERFLOW -> STAKCOVERFLOW
```

would require a minimum of one operation, which is to

```
    shift K before C.
```

Are there any good online examples of

1. Finding the minimum instruction set (I believe this is also often called the edit distance), and
2. Listing the instruction set

Thanks!

Comment: what language? Please provide a complete description of your problem, if you want to get a helpful answer

Comment: Take a look at this link: http://norvig.com/spell-correct.html It's pretty good.

Comment: I'm happy with any language that has string manipulation abilities. I'm personally trying to use ActionScript 3, but the problem itself is not language-specific.

Comment: @Edward K Huang but languages are OS dependent. I could tell you to use perl p.a. but under windows, it may work not exactly the same way and would be a huge overhead. Thats why i'm asking for the language =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is something known as the Levenshtein distance that tells you how many changes are needed to go from one string to another and there are many C# implementations, many other languages too.

Here's the wiki:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance

Edit: As TheHorse has indicated, the Levenshtein distance doesn't understand Shift changes, but there is an improved algorithm:

[Damerau-Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Damerau%E2%80%93Levenshtein_distance)

Comment: Levenshtein distance have no SHIFT operation.

Comment: Sure it does, well, it understands substitution anyway ... and that's the example Edward has represented. An improved algorith is Damerau Levenshtein which supports transposition as well as addition, deletion and substitution:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Damerau%E2%80%93Levenshtein_distance

Comment: Actually, sorry you're correct, substitution isn't the same as transposition. I'll update my answer.